# Contract transfer between two address, pay gas from third address

Tags: contract-invocation, address.transfer

The scenario is to transfer from Address B to Address C, deducting the transaction fee from Address.

Here A will have some ether amount, which should be used to deduct the gas.

The ERC20 Token Standard, has a method transferFrom, which takes `from`, `to` and `amount` as input.

What is the point of `from` here, does it always has to be the person signing the transaction (if so, then what's the reason behind having two method `transfer` and `transferFrom`)? Or it can be a different address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transferFrom` method will only work if the owner (the `_from` address) has allowed the receiver ( `_to`  address) to withdraw the funds, this is done by calling `function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)` .

The address calling the transfer (or transferFrom) function will be the one paying the gas for the operation.

Hence, if B call  `approve(address_C, 10)` , there will be no fund transfer but B will still have to pay some gas for this operation.

Then, A can call  `transferFrom(address_B, address_C, 10)`  and send fund from B to C, and only A will be paying gas for the transaction fees.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Betcheg answer, but both A and B must have ether to invoke transferFrom and approve transactions, respectively.

But is there a way, such that only A need to have ether. And so B and C would have only tokens, not ether?

One way that I imagine is to change the "normal" way to implement a ERC20 token.
For example, change tranferFrom method to give permition to an address, like the owner (or another person/address), to be able to call transferFrom method even if not at approved list:

```
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender] || msg.sender == owner);     // Check allowed
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;

    //Other require validations

     balances[_from] -= _value;
    // Add the same to the recipient
    balances[_to] += _value;

    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);

    return true;
}
```

Or create a complete new method transferByOwner that is independent of allowence:

```
function transferByOwner(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(msg.sender == owner); 

    //Other require validations

     balances[_from] -= _value;
    // Add the same to the recipient
    balances[_to] += _value;

    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);

    return true;
}
```

Though, one can reply that this give the owner full control to all token balances. Sure that's exactly right :)